# Which command line argument parsing Perl module to use?

Tags: perl

When I search CPAN for "argument parsing" it returns 1250 hits.

Can anyone recommend a Perl module for handling command-line arguments?

Comment: why the downvotes?  It's not _that_ subjective a question.

Comment: I have a chapter in _Mastering Perl_ to answer this exact question. You first have to figure out what sort of command-line option interface you want, then use the module that handles that.

Comment: I use [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard modules for this (included in the Perl distribution) are [`Getopt::Std`](http://p3rl.org/Getopt%3a%3aStd) and [`Getopt::Long`](http://p3rl.org/Getopt%3a%3aLong).